# Page reloads on $A.enqueueAction call

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have a lightning component embeded into a Visualforce page.

**VF page:**

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightningComponent" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:SetupContainerApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:SetupContainer",
                {},
                "lightningComponent",
                function(component) {
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Lightning App:**

```
<aura:application description="SetupContainer" access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:SetupContainer" />
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT"/>
</aura:application>
```

**Lightning Component:**

```
<aura:component description="SetupContainer" controller="SetupContactPointController"
                implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller:**

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAllFields");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var str = response.getReturnValue();
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Apex Controller:**

```
public with sharing class SetupContactPointController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getAllFields() {
        return '';
    }
}
```

When the component is loaded and action `action="{!c.init}"` called the VF page is refreshed. I found the issue happens on `$A.enqueueAction(action);` line.

If I run the same component as a separate tab (without VF page container) the code works fine and the refresh doesn't happen.

How to make it work in VF page?

Comment: Is this the complete VF page code? where have you added <apex:includeLightning/>  to the visualforce page. its needed to load lightning out libraries

Comment: @RedDevil, I've updated my question with a full VF page code.

Comment: I tried your code and it doesnt refresh for me.

Comment: @RedDevil, thank you. I will try to reproduce the issue inside of another salesforce dev instance and then update my findings here.

Comment: If possible put like a  video of issue. between there is no need to explicitly load dependencies for system events in your app

Comment: Ok. I will make the video. And thank you for event dependency additional info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74420/discussion-between-reddevil-and-mikhail-ivanov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the force* dependency inclusion from the the app markup and try.

```
<aura:application description="SetupContainer" access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:SetupContainer" />
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT"/> -- not needed
</aura:application>
```

Comment: @Mikhail - posted the answer